# Tracking outgoing transactions & malleability attack

Tags: raw-transaction, transaction-malleability

What is the best way (in terms of security or resources) to track my outgoing transactions through the RPC API?

I would like to be able to track them down using their tx id and also to have a fallback mechanism for when my outgoing transaction's id changes as a result of a malleability attack.

Answer (score 2):

I personally would look for newly spent outputs as opposed to TXIDs.  The outputs get spent the exact same way in a malleability attack.

So create a hash based off of the inputs into the transaction, and when a TX comes in calculate that internal hash and check off of that.